# How can I add input value in js array without cloning values?

Tags: javascript

I have simple js script that adds input values in array after clicking on input, it works as expected except that it duplicates values every time I'm clicking on another input, i.e. I click on input with value `5`, array now is `["5"]` then I click on input with value `4` and after that array is `["5", "5", "4"]`. I've tried if statement with check on e.target but it didn't help. How can I add only input value on which I click, not all checked input values? Here is the link on [pen](https://codepen.io/MegaZef/pen/vYBpVoE). My HTML markdown:

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="5">
  <input type="checkbox" value="4">
  <input type="checkbox" value="3">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">
</div>
<p></p>
```

And JS code:

```
let checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
let checkboxesChecked = [];
let p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

function getCheckedCheckBoxes(e) {
  if (e.target.checked == true) {
    for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[i].value);
        console.log(checkboxesChecked)
      }
    }
    p[0].innerHTML = checkboxesChecked;
    return checkboxesChecked;
  }
};

for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', getCheckedCheckBoxes);
}
```

Any help and tips would be appreciated.

Comment: so reset the array! Also makes no sense to only do it if checked. If they uncheck it, the array is wrong.

Comment: Also I need to store all checked values, so array can look like ["4", "2", "4", "3", "4", ]

Comment: "How can I add input value in js array without duplicates?" But you are saying it is supposed to have dupes??? WHAT??

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I've chosen wrong word

Comment: Checkboxes are the WRONG thing to use here. It should be buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said you want it to add the number that was clicked each time it's clicked to become checked, so if I click 5 (on) it's `["5"]`, then if I click it again (off) there's no change, and if I click it a third time we add `"5"` again for `["5", "5"]`. If so:

```
function getCheckedCheckBoxes(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        checkboxesChecked.push(e.target.value);
    }
    p[0].innerHTML = checkboxesChecked;
    return checkboxesChecked;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
let checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
let checkboxesChecked = [];
let p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

function getCheckedCheckBoxes(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        checkboxesChecked.push(e.target.value);
    }
    p[0].innerHTML = checkboxesChecked;
    return checkboxesChecked;
}
for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', getCheckedCheckBoxes);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="5">
  <input type="checkbox" value="4">
  <input type="checkbox" value="3">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">
</div>
<p></p>
```

Comment: I need to store all checked values, you can check one input multiple times

Comment: @АнтонПортнянко - Ah, okay, so if I click 5, 5, 4, you want to end up with `["5", "4"]` or ...? (That seems odd, because at that point the 5 checkbox is unchecked...) Do we ever remove something from the array?

Comment: If you click 5, 5, 4, we will end up with ["5", "5", "4"] but function works only when input is checked, so you will have to click 3 times (check input, uncheck, check same input again), we are not removing items from array, only store them.

Comment: @АнтонПортнянко - Okay, I've updated. If the rule is that simple, the code is too. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the array each time and you should not just update it when checked.

```js
let checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
let checkboxesChecked = [];
let p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

function getCheckedCheckBoxes(e) {
  checkboxesChecked.length = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[i].value);
      console.log(checkboxesChecked)
    }
  }
  p[0].innerHTML = checkboxesChecked;
  return checkboxesChecked;
}

for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', getCheckedCheckBoxes);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="5">
  <input type="checkbox" value="4">
  <input type="checkbox" value="3">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">
</div>
<p></p>
```

Personally I would use querySelectorAll

```js
let checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
let checkboxesChecked = [];
let p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

function getCheckedCheckBoxes(e) {
  checkboxesChecked = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input:checked")).map(cb => cb.value)
  p[0].innerHTML = checkboxesChecked;
}

for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', getCheckedCheckBoxes);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="5">
  <input type="checkbox" value="4">
  <input type="checkbox" value="3">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">
</div>
<p></p>
```

With your comments.... which still does not make sense with checkboxes, they should be buttons.

```js
let checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
let checkboxesChecked = [];
let p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

function getCheckedCheckBoxes(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) checkboxesChecked.push(e.target.value)
  p[0].innerHTML = checkboxesChecked;
}

for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', getCheckedCheckBoxes);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="5">
  <input type="checkbox" value="4">
  <input type="checkbox" value="3">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">
</div>
<p></p>
```

Comment: I need to store all checked values, you can check one input multiple times

Comment: Sounds like a checkbox is the wrong thing to use if that is the case.

Comment: Yeah, but it's the way I should do it, this is my task

Comment: And your title says no dupes... that is what the answer does.